# How do I enable a transparent QGraphicsPixmapItem to receive mouse click events?

Tags: qt, events

I have a QGraphicPixmapItem as a game piece in my program. It has three main states: red, blue, and blank. The problem is, when blank, the piece is not clickable.

When red, I change the pixmap of the piece to a red, vaguely checker-like png. When blue, I do the same. When blank, I use a completely transparent png.

This blank, completely transparent pixmap is why (as far as I can tell) events are passing right through it. When I redid it by changing the pixmap to the red checker, then manually resetting the opacity to zero, the same thing happened. When I left even 0.01 opacity in the newly-red piece, however, the event triggered.

Clearly, being transparent means events pass through you for a QGraphicPixmapItem. How do I change that and make it receive events? Or is my conclusion wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the correct behaviour as described by the [shapeMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicspixmapitem.html#ShapeMode-enum).

You can change it to use QGraphicsPixmapItem::BoundingRectShape which, as the documentation states:-

> ...does not take into account any transparent areas on the pixmap.

If you still need to obey transparency, then you could inherit from QGraphicsPixmap item and reimplement the shape function to set the opacity to 0.1, call the base class shape function and set it back afterwards.